# jEditable Editing and row addition

Tags: jquery, datatables

Please I am in dire need of help with jeditable and datatables. I have been posting questions but got no answers, hopefully I will get this time around.

I have some datatables that are populated via ajax call. They are well populated and the editable part works to an extent. However, I have three major challenges.

- If I try to add a new row to my table, it gives me an error, but it is actually saved to the database, so on refresh of the table, it is being populated with the data
- I have a button in the row of my datatables, on click of this button, I want to get the values in the row, but I am unable to get it. it gives me an an "undefined" output
- I have some select buttons in my jEditable plugin, they are also populated via ajax, however I want each option to have a unique ID. The problem is, how to configure its json data to look like what it accepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would need some example code to be sure but I've tried to highlight some help below:

- What is the error? How are you adding? If you are adding via .html("") this won't copy to core. I'd recomment invalidating the row so it gets re-added. I tried the alternative (.dataetc.. and had issue)

  table.cell( this ).invalidate().draw(false);
- Likely you need something along the lines of :

  $(this).parent();
  Bes thing I can recommend is to put a breakpoint in chrome and use some good ole console work - but ina  similar project I used the above to get the elements and assigned them to variable using nthchild of parent.
- Unique id would be fairly easy - give it a name like thisone- and use a counter which increments to give it a number.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. The error it gives me is this: "datatables warning: table id=xxxx - Requested unknown parameter xxxx for row xxx. For more information about this error please see http://datatables.net/n/4". That is the error its gives me when I try to add a data, however this data is saved to the datatbase. I am using datatable jEditables function to add, this is the link for that https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/EditCell.  The code for the click event can be found on my jsfiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/aadewojo/pext0hm9/2/.